# Implement ADABoost in MATLAB R2010a

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

I wanted to use AdaBoost in MATLAB R2010a. It seems it can be used using fitensemble which is available in the Statistics Toolbox which is not available in R2010a.

Any other workaround for this version of MATLAB, probably some open source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Googling "Adaboost MATLAB" you can find about four implementations on the first page of results. If you don't like any of those, either upgrade to a recent version of MATLAB and Statistics Toolbox, or write your own - its not that hard.

Comment: Thanks, I managed with http://www.csp.curtin.edu.au/downloads/bootstrap_toolbox.html